# How to connect heroku app with openshift app database

Tags: database, heroku, database-connection, cloud-hosting, openshift

I am having app on [Heroku](http://heroku.com) and of course on [Openshift](http://openshift.com)

Now, I would like to use a common database for them. So, how should I connect Heroku app with the Open Shift app database??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenShift blocks all incoming ports EXCEPT 80, 443, and 22. 
Like the answer above you will either need to set up a SSH tunnel with port forwarding between your two server (which seems VERY fragile to me)

OR

You can set up a web service on your openshift server to handle all the DB requests. This is what happens when you use something like mongolabs or fusiotables with heroku. The difference here is that you would need to write your own web service to expose the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use port forwarding for this kind of work,Try these article  http://bitsofinfo.wordpress.com/2012/06/05/how-to-access-your-openshift-mongodb-database-remotely-on-os-x/ or,
Otherwise you can use a piece of software which runs on your openshift server,which remotely execute your commands on database.For that try Google and note that The ports 0 to 18000 are blocked to incoming traffic.